# Can I get badge number with trigger.io

Tags: trigger.io

Trigger.io provides a forge.notification.setBadgeNumber method to set the ios badge number. Is it possible to retrieve the badge number with trigger.io?

My use case is that I have a messaging system where the badge number is the number of unread message - I want to decrease the badge number when the user reads a message. To do that, I need to know the current badge number...

Suggestion on better ways to implement this will also be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could easily write your own [native module](https://trigger.io/docs/current/api/native_modules/index.html) to get the current badge count in Trigger.io apps. I have one in use and the relevant function looks like this:

```
+ (void)getBadgeNumber:(ForgeTask*)task {
  NSNumber *count = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber]];
  [task success:count];
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

It seems like Trigger.io added the getBadgeNumber call to their [notifications module](https://trigger.io/modules/notification/current/docs/index.html#forgenotificationsetbadgenumbernumber-success-error). Available methods are:

- `forge.notification.setBadgeNumber(number, success, error)`
- `forge.notification.getBadgeNumber(success, error)`

If you're using the [Parse module](https://trigger.io/modules/parse/current/docs/index.html#forgeparsesetbadgenumbernumber-success-error) for push notifications you can even retrieve and set the badge number on the Parse server as of now.